# Where or when is it unsafe to clean using compressed air?

Tags: computers, cleaning

There's this lesson on ICT for us in cleaning computers and their equipment. One of the components that can be used for cleaning is something called compressed air.

Just to make sure, which computer equipment is/are unsafe to clean using compressed air or when is it unsafe to clean using it?

Comment: I'm curious whether you're talking about actual compressed air, or the butane aerosol cans used for cleaning, but either way this is off topic for this site.

Comment: "something called compressed air" is simply air under pressure - like blowing really hard to remove dust.  It is not some magical product.

Comment: @PeterBennett That's what it's called, and I'm not referring to it as a magical product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s many sources of compressed air. Potential problems are static discharge - moving air generates a static charge, moisture as the water vapour in the air condenses out, eye and breathing hazards from dust etc being blown around.
These hazards can be mitigated by various means.

Comment: Hearth makes the good point that typically when people talk about "compressed air" they mean spray cans of liquified hydrocarbons, which tend to be very flammable (unlike actual air). I imagine actual cans of compressed air are pretty rare, since you can't actual squeeze that much air into a reasonable can